# bibliographies and siunitx in pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I'm using `pandoc` to convert my TeX file in a `.docx` file. The formatting, equations and images work very well, but I have some issues:

1. References to images don't show properly. They show only the name
   of the image file, not the number, neither in the caption nor inside the
   text.
2. The bibliography doesn't show; the numbers of the references papers ([1],
   [2] etc.) also don't show.
3. In the LaTeX file I'm using the `siunitx` package; `pandoc` doesn't convert syntax like `\SI{5}{mm}`.

Can anyone help me?